# Can I create a rule file which imports rule(s) from another rule file?

Tags: java, rules, drools, business-rules

How do I (and can I) import Drools rules or functions into another Drools rules file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessary.

If you load two different rule files using the knowledge builder all the rules in both files will be available.

There's no need to import rules from a different DRL file because when you compile the rules are all in the same binary package.

Answer (score 0):

There is no import rule facility in drools. It does not allow importing rule from another package.